# Play pure tones in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I've seen countless infos on how to play a sound file, but how can I generate a specific audio tone (or several) at given Hertz in cocoa touch?

Answer (score 2):

One simple way: You've found sample code for playing audio files. Your audio file can be a sine wave. You can change the playback rate.

There are other ways if you go to the work of managing your own buffers.

Answer (score 1):

The low-level approach is using CoreAudio with the `kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO` and `kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded` audio units.
The SDK comes with some built-in CoreAudio units - you can't implement your own yet.
A good API to connect those units is AUGraph.
As you can't implement your own audio units that render a sinewave, you will have to use render-callbacks and attach them to the input bus of your mixer unit.
Fill out a `AURenderCallbackStruct` and connect it to your Graph with `AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback`

To generate the actual sinewave you could use something like [this](http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2000-May/014070.html) as render callback (the code is actually for the Mac but the render callback should work on the phone)

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gallagher's [example](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html) will help you:

"An iOS tone generator (an introduction to AudioUnits)"